# Technique to fix Maven Dependency when using Artifactory

Tags: maven, dependencies, repository, artifactory

So I get an error like
`Could not find artifact javax.xml.xquery:xqj-api:jar:1.0 in remote-repos`
which is telling me I have an issue with my setup in Artifactory.

The issue being things get cached and so even if I have resolved it I wouldn't necessarily know.

Should I create an alternate settings.xml for Maven that bypasses all mirroring and a very small pom.xml that only references the missing dependencies I'm interested in and repository statements referencing the repo's I think my dependency might be hiding in?

Or what is the best minimalist approach to gathering details of the repositories in need to add to the repository manager?

Comment: So you voted down the question. Why? How can I improve my questions or understand what I've done wrong if you don't provide feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the following approach:

1. [search](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Searching+for+Artifacts#SearchingforArtifacts-QuickSearch) for the required artifact in Artifactory. If you found it, make sure you are resolving artifacts from the repository containing it. The best practice here is resolving from a [virtual repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-VirtualRepositories) which aggregates all the repositories you need.
2. If you did not find the artifacts in Artifactory, try using [remote search](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Searching+for+Artifacts#SearchingforArtifacts-RemoteSearch). Remote search will look for the artifact in Bintray [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter).
3. If you did not find the artifacts in JCenter try using a service such as http://mvnrepository.com/. If you managed to find the artifact in a repository, add it to Artifactory as a new [remote repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-RemoteRepositories) (assuming you trust this repository and would like to use it). You can use [include/exclude](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Common+Settings) patterns to make sure only specific artifacts are resolved from this repository.
   Another option is downloading the specific artifacts you need from the remote URL and deploying them in a local repository such as ext-lib-releases.
   Again, make sure that whatever option you chose, your build is able to resolve the artifacts.
4. If you did not manage to find the artifact in any public Maven repository, try for searching the artifact(s) using Google and deploy the required files to Artifactory as mentioned in the previous item. Download only from sites you trust and verify you are downloading a legit/valid file.

Comment: Yes on #4 there is that element of risk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it guided me to the following solution.So in Maven you can have multiple Profiles. I set up a direct profile that had the various repositories in order

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to @drorb thanks for your answer it guided me to the following solution to my problem.

So in Maven you can have multiple Profiles. I defined two profiles "direct" and "artifactory" and set "direct" as my ActiveProfile.

Using the direct profile, i.e. the actual repo URLs', I added the repositories I found by doing searches until my build succeeded.

I then went into Artifactory and entered all the discovered repo's into its Remote Repositories list, and then edited the "remote-repos" virtual repository and set it to the list of Remote Repositories I just added.

Finally I switched my ~/.m2/settings.xml to the "artifactory" profile and rebuilt my project.